# How to avoid race condition when using BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync?

Tags: .net, backgroundworker, race-condition

In [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.BACKGROUNDWORKER.CANCELASYNC%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) about `BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync` method, there is a caution which says:

> Be aware that your code in the `DoWork` event handler may finish its
>   work as a cancellation request is being made, and your polling loop
>   may miss `CancellationPending` being set to **true**. In this case,
>   the `Cancelled` flag of
>   `System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` in your
>   `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler will not be set to **true**, even
>   though a cancellation request was made. This situation is called a
>   *race condition* and is a common concern in multithreaded programming.

What is the correct and good solution to avoid this *race condition*?

Here is my sample code, that provokes the apperance of this condition:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker bW;
    int bWsCount = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bW != null)
            bW.CancelAsync();
        bW = new BackgroundWorker();
        bW.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bW.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bW_DoWork);
        bW.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bW_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bW.RunWorkerAsync(0);
        bWsCount++;
        labelBackgroundWorkersCount.Content = bWsCount;
    }

    void bW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        if (e.Cancelled || worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            bWsCount--;
            labelBackgroundWorkersCount.Content = bWsCount;
        }
        else
            worker.RunWorkerAsync(1000);
    }

    void bW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        int sleepDuration = Convert.ToInt32(e.Argument);
        if (worker.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
        Thread.Sleep(sleepDuration);
        if (worker.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to avoid it, not every threading problem has a solution.  These things can be reasoned out when you push them to the extreme.  Imagine the code in your UI thread calls CancelAsync() a *nanosecond* before the worker thread completes.  Just as the thread is executing its last machine code instruction.  Clearly there's no possible way this could be detected by the thread.  Nor is there any possible way for the UI thread to see that the thread is on its last instruction.

This is not a real problem, just keep it in mind when you write your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.  If the e.Cancelled property is false then the worker completed anyway.  If necessary, you can simply && it with another bool that you set to true when you call CancelAsync().  Roughly:

```
    private bool cancelRequested;

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        cancelRequested = true;
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error != null) throw e.Error;
        if (!e.Cancelled && !cancelRequested) {
            // Completed entirely normally
            //...
        }
    }
```

Please *do* keep in mind that this not just a race in code.  The far more practical problem is that this is a race in the user's brain as well.  With the failure mode that everything completes normally a millisecond before the user clicks the Cancel button.

So as far as the user knows, the operation was canceled when in fact it was not.  This can have unpleasant consequences, ones you'll have to deal with by telling the user what *really* happened.  In which case it really doesn't make any sense to use the code snippet, it will work just as well if you *only* cancel the operation and allow it to complete anyway.

Comment: I like this answer.  However, isn't the original code essentially doing this by checking `worker.CancellationPending`?  As long as `CancelAsync` is only ever called on the ui thread, and `worker.CancellationPending` is checked on the ui thread then you avoid the race condition.  Right?

Comment: @Matt - CancellationPending is reset before RunWorkerCompleted runs.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I didn't know that.  That seems like a disservice.  For the analogous TPL example, I can check the CancellationToken on the UI thread and (as long as I only Cancel the CancellationTokenSource on the ui thread) I avoid the race condition.

Comment: Not really, it is intentional.  Acknowledging that its value is meaningless after the worker stopped running because there's no way to tell whether the worker actually acted on the value.  Same with CancellationToken.  Except for its more explicit ThrowIfCancellationRequested method, you can always tell when the worker aborted with an exception.  In which case you detect it from the exception, not the token.  That works for BGW as well of course.

Comment: Thanks for your continued dialog.  Regarding, "there's no way to tell whether the worker actually acted on the value". I thought that if the worker acted on the cancellation, they're expected to set DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel to true (which would in turn cause RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled to be true in the RunWorkerCompleted).  So then you could know that they acted on it (vs them "missing" the cancel due to the race condition).

Comment: In the TPL, I can know whether the task acted on the cancellation by checking whether the task was cancelled (i.e. they did a ThrowIfCancellationRequested). Also I can know that the task didn't act on the cancellation, but missed it due to the race condition by checking the cancellation token.

Comment: Here's how I use this to my advantage: Do a `ContinueWith` on the task that might  be cancelled specifying the ui thread scheduler and specifying OnlyOnRanToCompletion. On the first line of my continuation I check the cancellation token for a cancel.  If the task notices the cancellation, my continuation will not be called.  If the race condition occurs and my continuation is called, I check the cancellation token and don't do the work of the continuation.